# How to make this forloop count from 1-8?

Tags: php, for-loop, rows, dynamic-columns

I'm creating tables with 4 rows and 2 columns using this for loop:

```
   $row = 4; //Dynamic number for rows
   $col = 2; // Dynamic number for columns


   for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
      for($j=0;$j<$col;$j++){
        echo $i+$j.'</br>';
      }

  }
```

However, I cannot seem to get it to output 1-8 in numbers sequentially.

Would be grateful is someone knows how to do this?

Cheers

K

Comment: Maximum $i will ever be is 3 and for $j = 1, so all you can get it 4. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a bit of maths on the number output.  As each value of `$i` represents a set of columns (each being `$col` long), I use `$i*$col`, add the column (`$j`), but as `$j` starts at 0, I just add 1 for the final value...

```
$row = 4; //Dynamic number for rows
$col = 2; // Dynamic number for columns

for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$col;$j++){
        echo (($i*$col)+$j+1).'<br />';
    }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />
```

Comment: +1 from me for the right, simple answer... I just want to point out that there's an HTML error, it must be `<br />` (it was already wrong in the original post) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = 4; //Dynamic number for rows
$col = 2; // Dynamic number for columns

for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<$col;$j++){
    echo $i*$col + $j.'</br>';
  }
}
```